# Calculating length of stretched wire (before and after) based on resistance

Tags: electronics

For a university project; I'm interested if I can accurately calculate the lengths of a wire (or any electrical conductor) before and after stretching. I understand that there are multiple factors contributing to the increased resistance upon stretching. I.e. increased length, decreased area and piezo electric effect. However I'm interested in the possibility in calculating length change based on resistance accurately, taking into consideration as many of resistance-affecting factors as possible.

Comment: By how much are you expecting to stretch the wire? You can only elastically strain a typical metal wire by an amount of around 1% before parts of the wire start to plastically deform and failure takes place. Is that fine with you?

Comment: This idea stems from a university project I'm working on. Essentially I want to know if it's possible to (ACCURATELY) calculate lengths based on resistance. I know that there exist electrical conductors which can stretch to 5x their original length, so I want to know if I can go through with my original query.

Comment: What sorts of solid electrical conductors that can stretch to 5x their original length are you talking about? Give an example.

Comment: So my project is to design a spinal angle wearable device. My idea is to place attach a reference point on the coccyx area (stationary) and another point somewhere on the back. I would like to connect these two with an electrical conductor. Reference posture would be assumed when the patient is standing upright with the conductor being vertical. When the patient bends their back, the conductor would stretch (and so increase in length). Now I want to know whether I could use the changing resistance in the wire to calculate the increased length and then, the angle of the spine.

Comment: The link to conductors that can stretch up to 5x their original length: https://phys.org/news/2017-05-limits-elastic-conductors.html

Comment: Lots and lots of issues here. For one, you would be relying on the ability of the material to consistently show the same resistance when it has been stretched and then released back to it's initial state. Doubt that that is true to much accuracy. More likely that the material's resistivity increases over time as it undergoes strain-and-release cycling due to the gradual buildup of small defects. Also, note that the conductivity of this material dramatically changes when it is stretched, so...

Comment: ...the resistance of a wire doesn't change just due to geometry but also due to the changing nature of the material itself. The change in the intrinsic conductivity of the material itself under stretching further reinforces my view that it probably doesn't show very reproducible resistance behavior under repeated stretching-and-relaxation cycles. For your intended application, I think that you really need to get together with a good experimental physicist or engineer and do some brainstorming on a better approach.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, the project is just a concept so it won't be something that actually gets manufactured. I just need to prove how accurate it would be in terms of calculating the spinal angle. I found this product online which seems exactly like what I was thinking of: https://www.robotshop.com/uk/images-scientific-12inch-stretch-sensor.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwjvXeBRDDARIsAC38TP6cjtlA8pxexWwUuc007LjffW1oSvt-sh-Tvjiff6_LRbL6Fo78D00aAu7_EALw_wcB

Comment: With the proof I need to show how accurate my device would be in theory. Could you point me to any references that would be useful on calculating this increase in length from changing resistance?

Comment: I looked up this "Images Scientific 12" Flexible Stretch Sensor" device. There's a user manual for it, but I didn't find any spec sheets with serious information such as the reproducibility of the readings after repeated stretch-and-release cycles or if there is a cycle lifetime for the product. The device may be as simple as a rubber tube filled with graphite powder, with the resistance changing just due to changes in the length and cross-sectional area of the tube. ( http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/resis.html ).